# FATAL EXCEPTION: [com.google.android.gms.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$ChimeraService-Executor] idle

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dart-null-safety

I am developing a flutter e-commerce application, suddenly I get these errors without doing anything to the code

```
E/AndroidRuntime(30409): FATAL EXCEPTION: [com.google.android.gms.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$ChimeraService-Executor] idle
E/AndroidRuntime(30409): Process: com.google.android.gms, PID: 30409
E/AndroidRuntime(30409): java.lang.SecurityException: isIccLockEnabled: Neither user 10531 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE.
E/AndroidRuntime(30409):    at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2385)
E/AndroidRuntime(30409):    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2369)
E/AndroidRuntime(30409):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2352)
E/AndroidRuntime(30409):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2294)
E/AndroidRuntime(30409):    at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy.isIccLockEnabled(ITelephony.java:14946)
E/AndroidRuntime(30409):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(30409):    at com.excelliance.kxqp.platform.c.b.a.a.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(30409):    at com.excelliance.kxqp.platform.c.b.a.bg.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(30409):    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
E/AndroidRuntime(30409):    at $Proxy25.isIccLockEnabled(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(30409):    at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.isIccLockEnabled(TelephonyManager.java:14646)
E/AndroidRuntime(30409):    at rta.a(:com.google.android.gms@212621046@21.26.21 (150400-387928701):52)
E/AndroidRuntime(30409):    at rtb.b(:com.google.android.gms@212621046@21.26.21 (150400-387928701):3)
E/AndroidRuntime(30409):    at cobx.b(:com.google.android.gms@212621046@21.26.21 (150400-387928701):1)
E/AndroidRuntime(30409):    at ruy.<init>(:com.google.android.gms@212621046@21.26.21 (150400-387928701):8)
E/AndroidRuntime(30409):    at rva.b(:com.google.android.gms@212621046@21.26.21 (150400-387928701):3)
E/AndroidRuntime(30409):    at cobx.b(:com.google.android.gms@212621046@21.26.21 (150400-387928701):1)
E/AndroidRuntime(30409):    at ruz.a(:com.google.android.gms@212621046@21.26.21 (150400-387928701):0)
E/AndroidRuntime(30409):    at rnr.a(:com.google.android.gms@212621046@21.26.21 (150400-387928701):7)
E/AndroidRuntime(30409):    at com.google.android.gms.checkin.CheckinIntentOperation.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms@212621046@21.26.21 (150400-387928701):54)
E/AndroidRuntime(30409):    at com.google.android.chimera.IntentOperation.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms@212621046@21.26.21 (150400-387928701):2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

Comment: there is no such file, but there is AndroidManifes.xml.

Comment: yeah, that file.

Comment: as I see there are three files with that name in the android folder, one in the app/src/debug folder, one in the app/src/main folder, and another one in the app/src/profile folder. where should I add??

Comment: Try main first, then debug.

Comment: Why does this work, out of curiosity?  How did you know this was the right permission?

Comment: @RyanM I just googled the error log `E/AndroidRuntime(30409): java.lang.SecurityException: isIccLockEnabled: Neither user 10531 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE.
`